# Einstein summation convention: tensor multiplication with the identity?

Tags: metric-tensor, tensor-calculus, notation

Suppose we have the following expression $M_{\mu\nu}\omega^{\mu\nu}$, where $M_{\mu\nu} = [M]_{\mu\nu}$ and $\omega_{\mu\nu} = [\omega]_{\mu\nu}$. Now I tell you $w = I$ with $I$ being the identity. What does this mean for the expression? Are we now summing over all the entries of $M$ or just the diagonals? How do I write this in the Einstein convention? I am guessing the answer involves the Kronecker delta or the metric tensor but I'm not sure which one is the right way.

Comment: This might help some with the [index gymnastics](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ricci_calculus). It's at least some place to start though it also involves some more advanced notation.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First note that given a tensor $A$ with entries $A^{\mu \nu}$, the transpose of $A$ is defined as the tensor $A^T$ with entries
\begin{equation}
(A^T)^{\mu \nu} = A^{\nu \mu}.
\end{equation}
If you arrange the $A^{\mu \nu}$ in matrix form where $\mu$ labels the rows and $\nu$ labels the columns, doing $\mu \leftrightarrow \nu $ corresponds to the usual operation of matrix transposition, switching rows and columns.

If you write your expression as
\begin{equation}
M_{\mu \nu} w^{\mu \nu} = M_{\mu \nu} (w^T)^{\nu \mu},
\end{equation}
you see that what you want in matrix form is
\begin{equation}
\text{tr} \left( M w^T \right),
\end{equation}
where tr means trace, defined as the sum of the diagonal elements of a matrix (a tensor with two indices, one up and one down, corresponds to what we usually call matrices. This is because a matrix $B$ is defined as something which acts linearly on a vector $V^\mu$ and returns another vector $U^\mu$, so the index structure of $B$ must be such that both $V$ and $U$ have upper indices: $B^\mu_{\phantom{a} \nu} V^\nu = U^\mu$). Inside the trace we have the product matrix $M w^T$, whose form in index notation is
\begin{equation}
[M w^T]_\mu^{\phantom{a}\rho} = M_{\mu \nu} (w^T)^{\nu \rho}.
\end{equation}
The order of the indices is important, only if the $\nu$ indices being contracted here are next to each other can we claim that this is a conventional matrix product (that is why I transposed $w$). Now, take the trace of this object to find what you want
\begin{equation}
\text{tr} \left( M w^T \right) = [M w^T]_\mu^{\phantom{a}\mu}  =M_{\mu \nu} (w^T)^{\nu \mu}.
\end{equation}

Your choice of $w$ being the identity does not work very well in Minkowski space (which I assume you are working in), since you defined $w$ as an object with two upper indices, while the identity matrix has one index up and one down:
\begin{equation}
[I]^\mu_{\phantom{a} \nu} = \delta^\mu_{\phantom{a} \nu},
\end{equation}
as all matrices do. If you choose to use the inverse metric tensor $g^{\mu \nu}$ to raise one index of the identity, what you get is the inverse metric tensor itself
\begin{equation}
g^{\mu \rho} \delta^\nu_{\phantom{a} \rho} = g^{\mu\nu}.
\end{equation}
The matrix form of this equation is $g^{-1} I = g^{-1}$. Therefore if you choose $w^{\mu \nu} = g^{\mu \nu}$, your expression in Einstein notation is
\begin{equation}
M_{\mu \nu} g^{\mu \nu} = M^\mu_{\phantom{a} \mu} = \text{tr}(M).
\end{equation}
If you insist that $w$ should be the identity, you must modify your original expression to $M_{\mu \nu} w^\mu_{\phantom{a} \rho}$, and $w=I$ in this case gives
\begin{equation}
M_{\mu \nu} \delta^\mu_{\phantom{a} \rho} = M_{\rho \nu},
\end{equation}
whose matrix form is $M I =M$.

Comment: Very nice and clear explanation of how to pass from index to matrix notation! Had I seen this when I was taking my GR course!

Answer (score 0):

The summation convention, in its strictest form, is that an index that repeats in a monomial, once upstairs and once downstairs, is understood to be summed over - all of them, pairwise. Therefore, $M_{μν} ω^{μν}$ means $\sum_μ\sum_ν M_{μν} ω^{μν}$. Each application of the summation convention is a "contraction" by the corresponding index pairs.

This compensates for a gap that's created by the convention of Mathematicians of treating geometric objects algebraically and tensors as linear functionals and "avoiding" indices: they have no uniform notation that reflects the full diversity of ways to do contraction. The tensor $M_{μν}$ is a linear functional $M(u,v)$ of vectors that, themselves, are denoted $u = u^μ ∂_μ$ and $v = v^ν ∂_ν$, such that $M(u,v) = M_{μν} u^μ v^ν$ and $M_{μν} = M\left(∂_μ, ∂_ν\right)$; while the tensor $ω^{μν}$ is a linear functional $ω(α,β)$ of co-vectors $α = α_μ dx^μ$ and $β = β_ν dx^ν$, such that $ω(α,β) = ω^{μν} α_μ β_ν$, with $ω^{μν} = ω\left(dx^μ, dx^ν\right)$. A bunch of ad hoc stop-gap nomenclature then needs to be devised just to express the double contraction $M_{μν} ω^{μν}$, while avoiding writing the contraction directly by index-pairing. The nomenclature, whatever is devised, may handle that one use-case, but not the infinite number of other use-cases where index-pairing arise.

This leads to a schism between the mathematicians' literature and physicists' literature, and their respective languages, that would require a linguist (me) to reconcile. (Hi Chomsky, we're wrapping up the follow-up publication of the Category-theoretic/algebraic reification of your Chomsky-Schützenberger Theorem in a few days.)

Note that I said the Mathematician's notation "avoid" indices, because they actually don't. They just put them in another position. They're inside function brackets - which is nothing but a cosmetic change to fool oneself into thinking there are no indexes anymore.

So, the simplest convention is to just allow arbitrary co-vectors as super-scripts and arbitrary vectors as sub-scripts. Then, $ω^{αβ} = ω(α,β)$, $M_{uv} = M(u,v)$ and just grandfather in the index notation by $(⋯)^μ = (⋯)^{dx^μ}$ and $(⋯)_μ = (⋯)_{∂_μ}$. Then the identity tensor is just the contraction operator, itself:
$$I^α_u = u ˩ α = α_μ u^μ,$$
and is one and the same as the Kronecker delta
$$I^α_u = δ^α_u = δ^μ_ν α_μ u^ν = δ^α_ν u^ν = δ^μ_u α_μ,$$
which, in turn, the same as the "component-of" operator
$$δ^α_ν u^ν = α_u = u^α = δ^μ_u α_μ.$$

The grandfathering-in goes hog-wild totally on the loose:
$$
α_μ dx^μ = α = dx^α = dx^{dx^α} = ⋯, \hspace 1em u^ν ∂_ν = u = ∂_u = ∂_{∂_u} = ⋯, \\
dx^μ = dx^{dx^μ} = dx^{dx^{dx^μ}} = ⋯, \hspace 1em ∂_ν = ∂_{∂_ν} = ∂_{∂_{∂_ν}} = ⋯.
$$

It also expands to geometric objects that are **not** linear, but affine. Thus
$$
[u,v] = \left(∂_u v^μ - ∂_v u^μ\right) dx^μ = f^μ_{uv} dx^μ,\\
f^α_{uv} = [u,v] ˩ α = \left(∂_u v^μ - ∂_v u^μ\right) α_μ,
$$
which defines the "Lie bracket" and the corresponding "structure coefficients" object. It is not linear, but affine. Letting $g$ denote a scalar function:
$$f^{gα}_{uv} = g f^α_{uv}, \hspace 1em
f^α_{(gu)v} = g f^α_{uv} - (vg) δ^α_u, \hspace 1em
f^α_{u(gv)} = g f^α_{uv} + (ug) δ^α_v.$$
So, it is linear in the $α$ index, but only affine in the $u$ and $v$ indices.

In particular, for coordinate indices, it totally vanishes: $f^α_{μν} = 0$, since $\left[∂_μ, ∂_ν\right] = 0$.

The "covariant derivative" operator and the corresponding "connection coefficients" are another example
$$
∇_u v = u^μ \left(∂_μ v^ν\right) ∂_ν + u^μ v^ν Γ^ρ_{μν} ∂_ρ, \\
Γ^α_{uv} = \left(∇_u v\right) ˩ α = u^μ \left(∂_μ v^ν\right) α_ν + u^μ v^ν Γ^ρ_{μν} α_ρ.
$$
It is linear in $α$ and $u$, but only affine in $v$:
$$Γ^{gα}_{uv} = g Γ^α_{uv}, \hspace 1em
Γ^α_{(gu)v} = g Γ^α_{uv}, \hspace 1em
Γ^α_{u(gv)} = g Γ^α_{uv} + (ug) δ^α_v.$$

The other objects in common use are the Torsion operator and object:
$$T_{uv} = ∇_u v - ∇_v u - [u,v], \hspace 1em T^α_{uv} = T_{uv} ˩ α = Γ^α_{uv} - Γ^α_{vu} - f^α_{uv},$$
and the Curvature operator and object:
$$
R_{uv} = ∇_u ∇_v - ∇_v ∇_u - ∇_{[u,v]}, \\
R^α_{uvw} = \left(R_{uv} w\right) ˩ α = \left(∂_u Γ^μ_{vw} - ∂_v Γ^μ_{uw} + Γ^μ_{uν} Γ^ν_{vw} - Γ^μ_{vν} Γ^ν_{uw} - f^ν_{uv} Γ^μ_{μw}\right) α_μ
$$
which are all linear in all indices, and are therefore tensors.

Operators, with this convention, can also be tensors, by virtue of being linear in each of their indices. Thus,
$$
∂_u = u^μ ∂_μ, \hspace 1em
dx^α = α_μ dx^μ, \hspace 1em
T_{uv} = u^μ v^ν T_{μν}, \hspace 1em
R_{uv} = u^μ v^ν R_{μν}, \hspace 1em
R_{uv} w = u^μ v^ν w^ρ R_{μν} ∂_ρ
$$
are all linear in each index and therefore quality as operator-valued tensors; as also is the following operator which has no officially-recognized name that I'm aware of:
$$∂_{uv} = ∂_u ∂_v - Γ^ρ_{uv} ∂_ρ, \hspace 1em ∂_{uv} = u^μ v^ν ∂_{μν}$$
but underlies the torsion operator:
$$∂_{uv} - ∂_{vu} = -T_{uv}.$$